# Django 2.0 CreateView AttributeError

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Why I got **AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'day'**?

I want to create simple generict view for Editing blog post.

views.py:

```
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
   login_url = '/login/'
   redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
   model = Post
   form_class = PostForm
```

Post model in models.py looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        ret_url_context = {'pk':self.pk}
        if self.published_date:
           ret_url_context['slug'] = self.slug
           ret_url_context['year'] = self.published_date.year
           ret_url_context['month'] = self.published_date.month
           ret_url_context['day'] = self.published_date.day
        return reverse("post_detail",kwargs=ret_url_context)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('drafts/', views.DraftListView.as_view(), name='post_draft_list'),
    path('post/new/', views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/remove/', views.PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_remove'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/publish/', views.post_publish, name='post_publish'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post_detail_date"),
    path('post/<str:slug>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    ]
```

And finally my html form is siple post_form.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>New post</h1>

    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

My form in forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = 'title', 'slug', 'short_description', 'author', 'text', 'published_date'
        #fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'editable medium-editor-textarea postcontent'}),
            'published_date': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={},format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
        }
```

I dont know where I should start to find a solution. But I think the problem is in inserting date and time. I'm inserting into editor this text: `12.12.2018 13:45` or `2018-03-13 13:45` - both don't work.

Comment: Try `yy-mm-dd` format and show traceback.

Comment: I've edited my post, forgot to show forms.py. There I've include the date time format. I tried `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"` and `"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"`

Comment: You still need to show the full traceback. Without it we have no idea where in all this code the problem is happening.

Comment: Here is: http://dpaste.com/1BBQBKC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique_for_date` attribute on a model field should be set to name of  `DateField` or `DateTimeField`. It ensure that there will be unique record for the combination of fields using unique_for_date and the `DateField` or `DateTimeField` set to `unique_for_date`.

For example, if you have two field as:

```
published_date = models.DateTimeField()
slug = models.SlugField(unique_for_date="published_date")
```

then, Django wouldn’t allow the entry of two records with the same `published_date` and `slug`.

You can read more about this on [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#unique-for-date).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your SlugField. The `unique_for_date` parameter needs to point to a field containing a date or datetime - you have set it to point to a method, `publish`. Presumably you meant `published_date`.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. Thank you. Could you give me some info how did you find this solution through the tackback?

Comment: The traceback showed the problem was occurring when `_perform_date_checks` was called from inside `validate_unique`, which was enough of a clue to look for attributes which were setting uniqueness constraints.